# How do I "shift select" from object A to object B in outliner?

Tags: shortcut, pie-menu, select

An action i would do with SHIFT in many apps , here doesnt work...whats the right shortcut ?

Thank you  ! [image: image for illustration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can border select (<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> drag) the items. If you want to select the in the 3D View as well, do a <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> click and choose *Select*.

Comment: YESSS THANK YOU SIR ! Actually this is another question but, what about a general move , like Plane.001 to move it above OldRustCans_09 ? 
Thank you agan !

Comment: @kay Good question. Make it a new one, after uing the search function.